# footer overlapping with contents

Tags: html, css

Im trying to put the "Vaccet" picture as a footer but, it keeps on going next to the "UPM" picture.

[image]

I have tried removing the footer from the body. On the other websites I've made, the contents of the footer goes under the section above it but this goes next to it.

```css
   .column-2 {
      float: left;
      width: 33.3%;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .column-3 {
      float: right;
      width: 30%;
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 30px;
      padding
    }
    
    .section-team{
        text-align: center;
        
    }
    
    .members{
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .upm{
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    
    footer{
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 80%;
        
    }
    
    .footer-nav{
       display: inline-block;
       width: 100%
    }
```

```html
    <section class="section-team" id="team">
        <div class="row">
           <h2>team members</h2>    
        </div>
      <div class="column-2">
        <img src="img/faceexample.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
        <h3>Adam</h3>
      </div>
       <div class="column-2">
        <img src="img/faceexample.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
        <h3>Adam</h3>
      </div>
       <div class="column-2">
        <img src="img/faceexample.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
        <h3>Adam</h3>
      </div>
       <div class="column-2">
        <img src="img/faceexample.jpg"  class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
        <h3>Adam</h3>
      </div>
       <div class="column-2">
        <img src="img/faceexample.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
        <h3>Adam</h3>
      </div>
       <div class="column-2">
        <img src="img/faceexample.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
        <h3>Adam</h3>
      </div>
        <div class="column-3">
        <img src="img/upm.jpg" class="upm" alt="upm" style="width:30%">
        <h4>UPM</h4>
      </div>       
        </section>
         <footer>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                    <ul class="footer-nav">
                          <img src="img/Vaccet.jpg" alt="vaccet logo" 
                            class="logo">
                    </ul>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

I hope someone can show me how to fix the footer problem

Comment: the same question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/56326153/8620333 ? if so remove one of them or this one will get closed as duplicate

Comment: alright already deleted @TemaniAfif

Comment: Try adding `bottom: 0;` to the footer css

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the `<section>` is not clearfix-ed. When using `float` elements, it is essential that you clearfix the container (`.section-team` in this case)

Try the following CSS (The Clearfix Hack):

```
.section-team:after,.section-team:before{
  content:''
  clear:both;
  display:table;
}
```

Comment: for what `display: table` it does work without it... I think a better solution will be adding this to row class, for future...

Comment: Did you try my answer above? clearing the footer? Could you try it?

Comment: I have had issues like that with floats. They make your document loose flow somehow... And Clearing all the elements that comes after the floated ones solves the issue.

Comment: @Ivan nice point... but thats how the clearfix hack got registered in my mind long long ago... However I tried without the table display.. check here https://jsfiddle.net/9o2zsg3w probably you can specify why it doesnt work without the display table

Comment: @JonesJoseph thanks for explaining, here will work any value except `inline`, I never used `display: table`)

Answer (score 0):

This is a flowing issue. Footer sees the space and tries to squeeze itself within that space.

Try:

```
footer{
    clear: both;
}
```

Otherwise: you might want to give a `width: 100%` to your Section.

Comment: This method may work for the footer, but the parent of the float elements still remain unfixe.. check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2o4te3jm/ where the border of the parent is not applied to the floated elements...

Comment: In that case, you could use overflow: auto; That's how can get it right. https://jsfiddle.net/69u50bo4/1/

Comment: Humm.. there are different ways of clearfixing. It just depends on the user's preferences :)

Comment: I was merely answering 1 question "This method may work for the footer, but the parent of the float elements still remain unfixe.." The question was about the footer and not about the parrent, hence I didn't include that answer. Sometimes it's not about preference, it's about what solved it for you. Because I have often realized that the more we get connected the more we learn to do things the right way, which reminds us that we can't always regard the way we do things our preferences but just "the way we know how it's done"

Comment: Hmm :)   whatever you say mate